# CefSharp1: Custom HTTP SchemeHandler with fallback to default

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm writing an application where I need to override both the HTTP and HTTPS schemes with my own handler. However, I need to let any requests that are not handled fallback to the default handler and be processed normally. I thought I could just return "false" from ProcessRequestAsync but that doesn't work. Any insight would be appreciated. I'd rather not have to build my own "fallback" as it seems that it would be problematic.

I'm currently using 1.25.7 of CefSharp, however I did upgrade to version 37 and got the same results.

Here's the code to my SchemeHandler:

```
public bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, SchemeHandlerResponse response, OnRequestCompletedHandler requestCompletedCallback)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(request.Url);

    foreach (IUriInterceptor interceptor in _interceptors)
    {

        if (interceptor.canHandle(uri))
        {
            interceptor.handleRequest(request, response);
            requestCompletedCallback.Invoke();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

IUriInterceptor is my own class. I made it to better organize my custom handlers.

Comment: It turns out there is a way to override specific hosts for a given scheme using CefSharp1. Instead of overriding the entire http scheme, I've elected to override specific custom hosts and things are working much better. Instead of using "CEF.RegisterScheme("http", new SchemeHandlerFactory())" you can do "CEF.RegisterScheme("http", "custom.host", new SchemeHandlerFactory())"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by CefSharp.

The underlying CEF library does allow it in `CefSchemeHandlerFactory.Create()`:

> Return a new resource handler instance to handle the request or an empty reference to allow default handling of the request.

http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefSchemeHandlerFactory.html

However the C++ implementation in CefSharp always expects a handler to be returned, and so you can never tell CEF to allow default handling:

```
CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler> SchemeHandlerFactoryWrapper::Create(
    CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
    CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
    const CefString& scheme_name,
    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request)
{
    ISchemeHandler^ handler = _factory->Create();
    CefRefPtr<SchemeHandlerWrapper> wrapper = new SchemeHandlerWrapper(handler);
    return static_cast<CefRefPtr<CefResourceHandler>>(wrapper);
}
```

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/00b25f5e3fac20b94b3022019fdeefbac6f9e271/CefSharp.Core/SchemeHandlerFactoryWrapper.cpp#L19-L21

The source code of CefSharp would need to be changed for this to work.  They are very happy to guide contributors and to accept contributions to the project (remember, it's open source and free!).

Another alternative is to use the CefGlue project, which is a minimal wrapper around CEF that uses pinvoke, so it probably works out of the box there. However, integrating CefGlue into your WinForms or WPF app may be more difficult than CefSharp.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. However, this leads me to another question. What is the purpose of returning "false" from ProcessRequestAsync if there is no fallback mechanism?

Comment: @Dan returning false will cancel the request, just like aborting a HTTP request on a server.  Here is the CEF documentation on it: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/%28default%29/CefResourceHandler.html#ProcessRequest(CefRefPtr<CefRequest>,CefRefPtr<CefCallback>)